# Show that ${d\over dt} \Phi _t^* \mu= \Phi_t^* L_X\mu$, $\;\Phi _t$ the flow of $X$, $\mu$ a form.

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Let $\Phi _t$ the flow of a vector field $X$, and $\mu$ an $m$ form on a manifold $M$. I want to prove the following relation:

$${d\over dt} \Phi _t^* \mu= \Phi_t^* L_X\mu$$

I was looking for an elementary proof of the fact. Thank for your help.

Comment: This should just amount to writing down the limit definitions, changing $\lim\limits_{t\to t_0}$ to $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't get any other answers, this is proved in Proposition 12.36 in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.). The proof is only a few lines long.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It seem a very complete and useful book. On the proof, I'm having trouble understanding this step: 

${d\over ds} |_{s = 0}\; d(\theta_{t_0})^{*}_{p}\, d(\theta_s)^{*}_{\theta_{t_0}(p)} (A_{\theta_s (\theta_{t_0} (p))})    =  d(\theta_{t_0})^{*}_{p}\; {d\over ds} |_{s = 0}\; d(\theta_s)^{*}_{\theta_{t_0}(p)} (A_{\theta_s (\theta_{t_0}(p))})$. Can you please explain this step.

Comment: @user95747: It's just the fact that $d(\theta_{t_0})_p^*$ is a fixed linear map between two fixed vector spaces, and does not depend on $t$.  If $A:V\to W$ is any linear map and $f:\mathbb R\to V$ is a differentiable function, then $\frac d {ds}(A\circ f)(s) = A\big(\frac d {ds} f(s)\big)$.